# How to custom style meta tags in html

Tags: html, meta-tags, meta

How can we add **styling to meta tags** on our html page

I am using the following meta tag so that facebook will choose this image as thumbnail, So can i change the style of this image?

```
<head>
<meta property="og:image" content="<?=base_url()?>webimages/fav.png"/>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Meta tags are used for information. They cannot be styled in anyway and by the way, what's the use of styling it.

If you want to style an image just edit it in any image editing software and your image will be styled. :)

Simple.

Comment: Hmm, the image changes dynamically so no use of software or tools i guess

Comment: @Ramaraju.d if the image is changing dynamically then you cannot still style it through the meta tag.